# How to load multiple URLs to single express object?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I want to route two Tasks in the same file using express. Below is the code i have written. Only Resource task is getting executed. I want Project_teams task to work

```
app.use('/resources',resources);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

//

app.use('/Project_teams',Project_teams);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put your `/Project_teams` route above the 404 handler. Remove the 2nd handler

Answer (score 2):

The order of express middleware matters. When you are trying to hit `Project_Teams` the request is first running through your error middleware, throwing an error, and not continuing.

Also, it seems you are using middleware when you should be defining routes for `Project_Teams` and `resources`.

Here is what it should look like:

```
var express    = require('express'),
    app        = express();

app.get('/a', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('a');
});

app.get('/b', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('b');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.listen('3000', function() {
  console.log('listening');
});
```